# Extract specific information from text files (preferably with vba)

Tags: string, vba, information-extraction

My first post here, but have learned A LOT from the forum over the last couple of years already!

I have a lot of files with personal information, but they are pretty much all formatted differently. They are CV's, nothing more exotic than that...

I am putting these CV's in a database, but I have problems getting the info I need. I'm using VBA, but am open to anything. The name is in the filename, so that's easy. So is finding their email address (hoping they haven't put their references emails in as well). Post code a little trickier, but have a slow solution (matching up all words with a number in to a list of postcodes. There are nearly 3000, hence the slowness).

So there is of course phone numbers as well. Trouble is making sure it's not other numbers than phone numbers.

It would of course be perfect if I could extract everything neatly (like professional experience and education and all that), but cannot even begin to think how to make the program clever enough.

Thing is, I have seen a program do something like this, but not sure how efficient it was. Has anybody had the same / similar tasks? Or any ideas to go about this?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 1):

Regular expresions are the way to go. You'll find plenty of web sites with expressions for purposes like extracting email addresses (http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html). Word's search and replace also has a regular expression mode known as Use Wildcards.

```
xmlstring = "<Function IDREF=""TST_RxRccsMatrix_Rx64"" Start=""2011-04-07T14:21:35.593000+02:00"" Status=""Success"" Tags=""SystemSerialNumber:41009"" End=""2011-04-07T14:29:16.625000+02:00"">"
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "IDREF=""([a-z0-9_]+)"""
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = True
Set Matches = regEx.Execute(xmlstring)
If Matches.count <> 1 then msgbox "no match or too many"
For Each Match in Matches
      Msgbox match.submatches(0)
Next
```

Comment: I cannot believe there is this massive field of regular expressions I didn't know about! I was searching high and wide for "find specific string in text" and the sorts... Thank you very much! This is surely the way to go if it is possible at all. I cannot mark your answer up as I'm too new here, sorry. @triggeradeadcat